# docker/fastapi/peewee - can connect to mysql on host, but can't in docker container

Tags: python, mysql, linux, docker, fastapi

Losing my mind a little with this networking stuff

Context:

- I'm working on a remote ubuntu server
- I have a fastapi app that uses peewee to interact with the database
- I am trying to learn docker, by containerizing this app
- The MySQL service is not containerized, but running on the host server.
- I am not using docker compose

I have a problem where my fastapi runs PERFECTLY fine when run through the terminal (using uvicorn), but when I dockerize the app, it returns an error saying it cannot connect to the MySQL server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 189, in __call__
    with collapse_excgroups():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_utils.py", line 93, in collapse_excgroups
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 191, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/main.py", line 28, in add_process_time_header
    db.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3231, in connect
    with __exception_wrapper__:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3059, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peewee.py", line 192, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3232, in connect
    self._state.set_connection(self._connect())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4201, in _connect
    conn = mysql.connect(db=self.database, autocommit=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc
peewee.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '5da987ec678f' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

# I've tried commenting this out
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# I've tried commenting this out too
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

here is the db.py and mre.py file
https://pastebin.com/7r71AYPx
(minimum reproducible example)

What I've Tried:

- Editing the my.cnf file to set `bind-address="0.0.0.0"`
- Making sure my database string is correct in ALL REGARDS
- Setting the IP of the connect string to:

  - 172.17.0.1
  - The IP of the server itself
  - localhost
- Making sure the user is able to access from all hosts in mysql `%`
- MySQL is indeed listening on 0.0.0.0 and port 3306
- I can 100% confirm that the API works when I run `uvicorn main:app --reload --port 8000`
- I am fairly confident I don't have any firewalls (I have never set anything up)
- I `docker exec` into the container, and I'm able to log into mysql (???)

I cannot figure it out, SOS

Comment: I can share my fastapi code and the code that instantiates the peewee mysql connection, but since it works through the terminal, I don't think it will help much

Comment: Hi! Please share the code snippet for your database connection (the lines that are triggering the error).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7r71AYPx here is a document with the minimum reproducible example

Comment: I thought it could be an error with peewee specifically, but after switching to sqlalchemy, the same error is present

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to directly include the database connection information, and how you're starting the container(s)?  Have you read through [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), which discusses the case of a container application connecting to a non-container database on the same system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a local MySQL for testing:

```
docker run --rm --name mysql -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 2

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "mre:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

`requirements.txt`

```
uvicorn==0.27.0.post1
fastapi==0.109.2
python-dotenv==1.0.1
peewee==3.17.1
PyMySQL==1.1.0
cryptography==42.0.2
```

`mre.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from db import db
 
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
 
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request, call_next):
    if db.is_closed():
        db.connect()
 
    response = await call_next(request)
 
    return response
 
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": f"Hello World!"}
```

`db.py`

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from peewee import MySQLDatabase
 
load_dotenv()
 
username = os.getenv('USERNAME')
password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
hostname = os.getenv('HOST')
database = os.getenv('DATABASE')

db = MySQLDatabase(
    database, user=username,
    password=password, host=hostname, port=3306
)
```

`.env`

```
USERNAME=root
PASSWORD=password
HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE=mysql
```

I renamed `HOSTNAME` to `HOST`. This is important and it won't work with `HOSTNAME`.

Now, since MySQL is running on port 3306 of the host, we can use host networking to give access:

```
docker build -t mre . && docker run -p 8000:8000 --net host mre
```

Screenshot below illustrates setup, with app (top left) and MySQL (bottom left) running.

[image]

Using host networking is not ideal. There are options:

1. Wrap up both the API and the database using Docker Compose.
2. Use the IP address for the database server.

With the second option, I check my local IP:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.1.69 172.17.0.1 172.18.0.1 172.20.0.1 172.19.0.1
```

And update `.env` accordingly.

```
USERNAME=root
PASSWORD=password
HOST=192.168.1.69
DATABASE=mysql
```

**Important:** Don't use `HOSTNAME`. Rather use `HOST`.

Now can run without host networking.

```bash
docker build -t mre . && docker run -p 8000:8000 host mre
```

Comment: 1. Thank you for taking the time to reproduce the issue. 2. I have tried using the server IP for the `HOST`, it still gives me the same error. 3. I too, am able to get it working with using the `--net host` options, but running it any other way doesn't work

Comment: let me know if you need specific information about my system

Comment: What do you get when you run `hostname -I`?

Comment: I FOUND THE ISSUE. Apparently within the container, the `HOSTNAME` environment variable is reserved for the ID of the container itself. When I was bringing the variables in from the .env file, it wasn't setting `HOSTNAME` because it was already reserved (or something). When I changed the variable name to `HOST`, it worked!

Comment: If you want to modify your answer with this information, I will accept it

Comment: Will do. My original answer used `HOST` but I have not highlighted this in two places in the answer. Thanks for confirming that this was the problem.